# Using altFormat and altField in jquery UI datepicker range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to get range of dates "from" and "to" to add it to my DB. I use altFormat and altField to capture the date in DB format (yy-mm-dd) while displaying normal date format in the UI using Datepicker jquery UI component.

My question is: How do I use this in the Datepicker UI range. Where can I specify the altField for my from and to datepickers?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

My Code:

```
var dates = $( "#hotel_display_checkin_date, #hotel_display_checkout_date" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#hotel_checkin_date",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option1 = this.id == "hotel_display_checkin_date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",

                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings ),
                    options = {option1: date}
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", options );
        }
        });
```

I tried adding the altField option to options = {option1: date}, but that does not work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're trying to use the same `altField` for both the check-in and check-out dates:

```
altField: '#hotel_checkin_date'
```

If you bind them separately:

```
var opts = {
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) { ... }
};

$('#hotel_display_checkin_date').datepicker(
    $.extend({
        altField: '#hotel_checkin_date'
    }, opts)
);
$('#hotel_display_checkout_date').datepicker(
    $.extend({
        altField: '#hotel_checkout_date'
    }, opts)
);​
```

so that you can specify separate `altField`s then things should work better.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bJ8bh/1/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle demo. I really understand the use of jquery.extend() now.

Comment: @swordfish: Just remember that `$.extend` modifies its first argument so you'll see a lot of `x = $.extend({}, ...)` things used.