# jQuery UI datepicker Select Range not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to make [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) select a date range (disable options that cause End-date to be before Start-date) as demonstrated [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range). But it is not working. Here is my code

```
$( "#fromDiv" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: '-1y',
  yearRange: "-5:+0",
  altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  altField: '#from',
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#toDiv" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( "#toDiv" ).datepicker({
  yearRange: '-5:+0',
  altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  altField: '#to',
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#fromDiv" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
```

Help.

Comment: Did you add `class="datepicker"` to your divs?

Comment: Just tried that. It didn't make a difference

Comment: Try changing both `$("#fromDiv")` and `$("#toDiv")` to reference your textboxes instead of divs

Comment: That breaks my datepicker. [altField](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField)  is meant to target a different input

Comment: I need to target divs because I need to use the [inline display](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline). And I have tried changing the call in `onClose` to work on the textboxes. That also doesn't work

Comment: @MarcoPrins what do you mean its not working?  elaborate and post a fiddle  demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I also have the same problem a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamn/mR75q/2/) has been added to explain the problem exists only with altFormat option added fiddle without altFormat works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shyamn/mR75q/3/)

Comment: Found answer here this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611891/using-altformat-and-altfield-in-jquery-ui-datepicker-range